# Object become NIL

Tags: ios, objective-c, pointers, exc-bad-access

i'm a beginner in iOS and I go into a problem that I can't solve alone.

Cnx.h:

```
NSString* _ip;
int * _port;

@interface Cnx : NSObject
-(int*) getPort;
-(void) setPort: (int*) pPort;
```

Network.h:

```
Cnx* _lan;
Cnx* _wan

@interface Network: NSObject
-(Cnx*) getLan;
-(Cnx*) getWan;
-(void) setLan: (Cnx*) pCnx;
-(void setWan: (Cnx*) pCnx;
```

Manager.h:

```
Network * _network;
@interface Manager: NSObject <NSXMLParserDelegate>
-(Network*)getXml; // Xml parsing fill _network return correct object (not nil)
```

In my view.m:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        Network *_net = [[[Manager alloc] init] getXml];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) anotherMethod {
    // Want to access to _net value, but object is nil..
}
```

My Bp Object is correctly fill, but when I wan't to use it, he becomes "nil". I understand that it is a story of pointer, but I didn't find the solution...
I hope my example is explicit.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Post the minimal real code that produces the issue.

Comment: Is this exactly how your code looks? Because if it is then it doesn't work at all no mind something becoming `nil` we don't work with fake code that is a one fast track ticket to getting your question closed. Please post your actual code.

Comment: Please format ur post in proper manner. he becomes nil, what does it mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring the `_net` value in your `init` method instead of **globally in the class**.

So you should have a `property` like this in your `@interface`:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Network *net;
```

and the code:

```
-(id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        _net = [[[Manager alloc] init] getXml];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Also your code is totally wrong, you should have this for example:

```
@interface Cnx : NSObject {
    NSString *ip;
}

@property (nonatomic) int port;
```

`@proeprty` because i see you are using **getter** and **setter** method, and `@property` is **auto** `@synthesized` so you have a default **setter** and **getter** methods for your var.

The `ip` variable instead is a normal instance.

It is clear that you don't have clear how **ObjC** works (maybe also OOP?). So i encourage you to read a bit about this.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Going to read more about @property

Comment: please select the answer as right if you solved your question.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now it's works and i've finally understand properties ^^!